# Formatting a date in javascript till the millisecond

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-ajax

We are using the following js lib from Microsoft
https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js

```
var datetimehigh = new Date(2011,01,12,14,45,55,596);

var sDate =  datetimehigh.format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss sss");
```

I cannot get the millisecond part to work.Note that format comes from Microsoft's Mvc Ajax lib.

Comment: Have you tried capital S for the milliseconds part?

Comment: did you try "l" (lowercase L)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's indicated by an **f**:

```
"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss fff"
```

Comment: Its not working as expected: myDateTime.format("mm-dd-yy HH:MM:ss fff") gives: "12-03-18 11:28:49 fff"

Answer (score 41):

If you are using the native [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) javascript object, you can simply use [`.toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method to get a formatted string with milliseconds:

```js
const date = new Date();
const dateString = date.toISOString(); // "2020-01-06T19:57:12.146Z"
```

Note that using [`.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) won't give you milliseconds precision.

Comment: Also note that `toISOString()` will change the time to UTC. The timezone offset can be removed before formatting with `date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset())`

Answer (score 16):

Use 'S' for milliseconds formatting:

```
"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS"
```

Comment: How to increase the milliseconds precision to 6 decimal places?

Answer (score 8):

Using the date format library, it should be something like this:

```
var nowMilliseconds = new Date().format("yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss l");
```

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

`L` for milliseconds with two digits

`l` (minus) for milliseconds with three digits

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for.  This is great for use in Node.js with the ported dateformat module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat

Comment: Great! Works as expected: myDateTime.format("mm-dd-yy HH:MM:ss.l")
"12-03-18 11:28:49.000"

Comment: Having trouble with `new Date()`:  _(intermediate value).format is not a function"_

Comment: @StephenBoesch it's prototype used to be provided by https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat, but is being deprecated. You could still use the library tho.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it:

```
function date_to_string_with_milliseconds(date){
  let date_str = date.toString() 
  let date_without_milliseconds = new Date(date_str) // truncated date since milliseconds are not included
  let milliseconds_delta = date - date_without_milliseconds
  let date_str_with_milliseconds = date_str.replace(/(^.*:\d\d:\d\d)(.*$)/, `$1:${milliseconds_delta}$2`)
  return date_str_with_milliseconds
}
```

Usage:

```
date_to_string_with_milliseconds(new Date(Date.now())).toString()
// outputs 'Wed Nov 30 2022 16:40:42:991 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)'
```

Doing it this way has a couple of advantages:

1. The date string that you get as output can be converted back to a
   Date object.
2. This doesn't change the original date object in any
   way since you only need a string representation.